# Extract only properties that have value in object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that looks like this for example:

```
let data = {
 color: "green",
 color1: "red",
 color2: null,
 color3: 34,
 color4: null,
 color5: true,
 color6: [],
}
```

I want to extract only the properties that have value and make a new object. So this new object would look like this:

```
   let data = {
     color: "green",
     color1: "red",
     color3: 34,
     color5: true,
    }
```

This would be dynamic, properties and values can change but at the end I always wanna make an object that has just values. What would be some practical way to do it?

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: How about if value is `{}`?

Comment: if there is no value it must stay null, but properties can also be empty arrays and empty objects which would count as having no value in my case

Comment: What if value is an empty string?

Comment: I gave it a try and I don't know how to do it. 
Empty string also counts as having no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `new object` by following the steps mentioned below :

- You can iterate through the keys using `Object.keys`
- Then, you can use `Array.reduce` to convert the array of keys into the transformed object.
- In `acc`, you will get the accumulated object.
- In `curr`, you will receive the current key
- Create a function `isEmptyObject` where you can define rules to check if present or not. As per your example, I have checked for `null` and `Array length`. You can modify this function.

```js
let data = {
 color: "green",
 color1: "red",
 color2: null,
 color3: 34,
 color4: null,
 color5: true,
 color6: [],
}

var newObj = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (isEmptyObject(data, curr)) return acc;
  acc[curr] = data[curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

function isEmptyObject(obj, key) {
  return obj[key] === null || Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length === 0;
}

console.log(newObj);
```